# Parse error in globbing filenames containing dashes in zsh

Tags: macos, shell, terminal, zsh, mdls

When I run `mdls -name kMDItemFSName -name kMDItemDateAdded -raw *` in zsh in a folder containing the directory `- Java Code`, I get the following error:

`` mdls: unrecognized option `- Java Code' ``

How can I fix this? I tried using `"*"`, but it didn't glob at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is because of the `-` option in one of the directories. Usually the command line flags are given following a `-`. A folder name as `-Java Code` is being treated as one such flags to `mdls` command which it doesn't like. Usually we provide an end of command line flags separator by providing a `--` upon which the shell realizes that no more command line flags are expected.

```
mdls -name kMDItemFSName -name kMDItemDateAdded -raw -- *
```

This way since we signaled that the command line flags are done, a folder name containing a leading `-` should be parsed properly.

The problem is a frequently occurring one and can be simply reproduced by a simple `mv` command and creating a file containing a `-` and when trying to move the file, the command would fail. It needs to be fixed by doing `mv --`

Most of the shell built-in commands and GNU tools support this option. Also POSIX recommends this too. See it from one of their guidelines. See [POSIX Utility Conventions - Guideline 10](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html#tag_12_02)

Comment: Oh, you're right. ‍♀️ I had forgotten `--`. What can one do if the utility in question doesn't support `--`? I mean, why isn't there something akin to "*"? Or is there?

Comment: An interesting note is that there is no `-Java Code`, but `- Java Code`, which is obviously not an option ...

Comment: @HappyFace: Most of the commands should support it. POSIX defines it too

Comment: @HappyFace The results of a glob expansion aren't subject to word-splitting, so `mdls` is getting a single argument `- Java Code`, not three arguments `-`, `Java`, and `Code`. Any argument starting with `-` is treated as an option, whether or not the `-` is followed by a space.